# Column order is not preserved when retrieving records from database in mulesoft

Tags: java, mule, mulesoft, mule4

The database connector is returning the results in an incorrect order. When a select query is made, the results return in an order that does not match the order of the select statement.

Database query gives a resultset with an order of columns different that the one JDBC's component returns while executing same query.

First query gives columns:

```sql
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM (SELECT COLUMN_NAME, CASE WHEN
SUBSTRING(COLUMN_NAME,1,CHARINDEX('_',COLUMN_NAME,1) - CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('_',COLUMN_NAME,1)= 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) = '' THEN COLUMN_NAME ELSE SUBSTRING(COLUMN_NAME,1,CHARINDEX('_',COLUMN_NAME,1) - CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('_',COLUMN_NAME,1)= 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) END  GROUP_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='XYZ') AS TEST_DATA WHERE GROUP_NAME IN ('A', 'B')
```

The second query uses the columns and return data:

```sql
SELECT columnanames FROM XYZ
```

which is same as

```
SELECT X,Y FROM XYZ
```

The response comes as:

> Y,X

instead of

> X,y

I need to preserve the order.

Comment: Please provide more context of the issue. Why do you need to preserver the order of the result? Are you using string concatenation in DataWeave to create the second query? Are you doing a JDBC query from a Java method to compare? What is the difference between first query and second query? The use case is no fully clear. Maybe if you show more complete snippets of the flow (in XML as text, no screenshots) it would be easier to understand the logic.

Comment: Also a sample of the input for the second transformation would be helpful

Comment: in UI side, I need to preserve the order. First query get all the column from the table in an order and i am using all columns in second query to get data. First query results: X, Y so second query would be SELECT X,Y from ABC table but the results come as Y, X but I had solved it using this code on transfrom message:%dw 2.0
var a =payload map (value,key) ->
    vars.groupColumn.COLUMN_NAME map(val)->
    value filterObject ((value,key) -> val contains key)
var result = a map($ reduce ((item, acc) -> acc ++ item))
output application/json
---
result map($)